# Eclipse 4. 2 Java Console Change Background Color

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I have been trying to change my Java console color but the run/debug preferences I have set does not seem to work. I have installed the "Eclipse Color Themes" and "Eclipse Chrome" plugins and they work great.

Answer (score 12):

I tried changing that setting on an older version and it worked.

Perhaps a plugin is causing this issue. You could remove them one by one until it works again.

Or perhaps it's a bug with 4.2. Try a previous version.

Or check the bug repository: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

[image: Image of working setting]

Comment: Works for me in Juno 4.2.1.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your settings and console?  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Changes for me didn't actually take place until I ran a program, then the background color updated.

Answer (score 0):

In preference (clicking on "Eclipse" on mac, "Window" on PC or Linux) section, search for "console". Under "Build/console", set the colours you wish to apply. Restart Eclipse, and build your project. You should see your preferred colour scheme in dark mode while the console is displaying the output of the compilation process.

Settings under "Run/Debug" becomes active whenever you hit the run/debug project and not when you build it. So you may wish to keep the same settings for both "Build" and "Run/Debug" options.